# get meta tags for api in rankmath

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I want to use Rankmath function in my Site Api for reading head and breadcrumb. Previously we used Yoast to do this. I’m sending you the code I used in Yoast. Is this option available in Rankmath?

‍‍‍‍`if (function_exists('YoastSEO')) { $meta_helper = YoastSEO()->classes->get(Yoast\WP\SEO\Surfaces\Meta_Surface::class); $meta = $meta_helper->for_post($post->ID); $output['head'] = $post->yoast_head = $meta->get_head()->html; $output['breadcrumbs'] = $post->yoast_head = $meta->breadcrumbs; }`

i want this API for use in nextJs project